# My volume slider functions but the button just stays in one place. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, react-hooks, jsx

I'm using this function above the return.  The div (below) is in the return.  The result that I get is a volume slider that functions.  However, visually the slider button never moves.  How can I fix this to make the button show where the volume is?

```js
const Component = () => {
  const setVolume = (e) => {
    audioRef.current.volume = e.target.value / 100;
  };

  return (
    <div className="volumeControl">
      <button onClick={() => audioMute()}> Mute </button>{" "}
      <input
        min={0}
        max={100}
        value={50}
        step={1}
        onChange={setVolume}
        type="range"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: The value seems to be hardcoded to `50`. Should it not be using state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button never moves because its value is fixed to 50.
You could use the `defaultValue` attribute instead of `value`.
Value is used with [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and should be bound to local state.

Comment: That fixed it!  You're awesome.  I didn't even know that attribute existed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As value is variable try to store it in the local state using useState hook

```
let [range, setRange] = useState(50)
const setVolume = (e) => {
   setRange(e.target.value / 100)
}

return(
<div className="volumeControl">
    <button onClick={() => audioMute()}>Mute</button>
    <input 
        min={0} 
        max={100} 
        value={range} 
        step={1}
         onChange={setVolume} 
        type="range"
    />
</div>
)
```

or

I think you are missing the ref attribute for an input element

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
....
let audioRef = useRef()

   <input 
        min={0} 
        max={100} 
        value={50} 
        step={1}
         onChange={setVolume} 
        type="range"
        ref ={audioRef}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use `useState()`? I think it's better for your case since you only need the volume value. Also you can set the initial volume there. `useState(50)`.
Try this code:

```js
const Component = () => {
  const [volume, setVolume] = React.useState(50);
  const handleVolumeChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setVolume(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="volumeControl">
      <button onClick={() => audioMute()}> Mute </button>{" "}
      <input
        min={0}
        max={100}
        value={volume}
        step={1}
        onChange={handleVolumeChange}
        type="range"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: The first answer in fixed it, but I'll spend some time studying yours.  Still so much to learn.  Thanks for this.